# can't get html digram to appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a diagram for HTML using JavaScript. The HTML page should contain a div container, where the diagram belongs.

I want to do this using a function that i've main; digram(uDivHTML, uList, uWidth). The first parameter takes a div inner html, as shown in the code below by the variable gram.

The seccond parameter should take an array. The array is supposed to have a string, then a number, and so on..

The third paramter should take a number that is used to multiply the length of each pilar.

Why is this not working? I have been trying different debuggers, and look over it many times, but can't seem to find out why. Any help is appreciated ;)

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "gram"></div>
    <button id = "btn">123</button>
    <script>
        var gram = document.getElementById("gram").innerHTML;

        var myList = [
          "norge",20,
          "svergie",17,
          "danmark",23,
          "england",11,
          "usa",64
        ];

        function diagram(uDivHTML, uList, uWidth) {
            for(var index = 0, colIndex = 0; index < (uList.length - 1); index+=2, colIndex++) {
                var col;

                switch(colIndex) {
                  case 0: col = "red";
                  case 1: col = "blue";
                  case 2: col = "yellow";
                  case 3: col = "green";
                  case 4: col = "orange"; colIndex = 0;
                }

                var wid = uWidth * uList[index + 1];

                uDivHTML += 
                "<div style ='height:20px;display:block;color:white;background-color:"+col+";width:"+wid+"px;'>"+
                  uList[index]+"</div>";
            }
        }

        var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

        btn.onclick = diagram(gram, myList, 10);

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, your `diagram` function builds a string but doesn't do anything with it. The HTML string you extract on the first line of the code has been detached from its original context many times over, updating the `uDivHTML` parameter doesn't automatically update the page contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with you code,

- gram variable is a string. But when you want the concatenated string to be displayed on the page, you need to explicitly update the value to the DOM element using innerHTML for example.

  - You are missing break statement in your switch case.
  - You need to give a event handler that has a signature like 
    btn.onclick = function(event){}.
    But you have a signature like this btn.onclick = diagram("", listArray, 10) . When you have something like this, your method wouldn't get the parameters you intend to pass.

I have modified your code a bit to make it work.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var gram = document.getElementById("gram");

  var myList = [
    "norge", 20,
    "svergie", 17,
    "danmark", 23,
    "england", 11,
    "usa", 64
  ];

  function diagram(uDivHTML, uList, uWidth) {

    for (var index = 0, colIndex = 0; index < (uList.length - 1); index += 2, colIndex++) {
      var col;

      switch (colIndex) {
        case 0:
          col = "red";
          break;
        case 1:
          col = "blue";
          break;
        case 2:
          col = "yellow";
          break;
        case 3:
          col = "green";
          break;
        case 4:
          col = "orange";
          colIndex = 0;
          break;
      }

      var wid = uWidth * uList[index + 1];

      uDivHTML.innerHTML +=
        "<div style ='height:20px;display:block;color:white;background-color:" + col + ";width:" + wid + "px;'>" +
        uList[index] + "</div>";
    }
  }

  var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
  btn.onclick = function() {
    diagram(gram, myList, 10);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="gram"></div>
<button id="btn">123</button>
```

Comment: Thanks you! I have little expericne with the html DOM so I didn't think this was a problem, but when you point it out I can see how that makes sense. I removed the break statements in frustration while debugging, when I was about to give up, and that's also when I added the button since I couldn't get winow.onload to work on jsfiddle. Thak you again, for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how you actually update the content of the div#gram. You have to assign the result of uDivHTML to the innerHTML of the div.